# Extend Facebook Access Token javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I've already had a look around and i can't seem to find an answer to this, I'm needing my access token to last longer than the 2 hours that it currently does. unless you are able to suggest another method of getting a json result. Thanks

Heres my code

```
//first define a function
//include two files where rows are loaded
//1.js
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'json',
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/147733805246675?fields=posts&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBALZA1JuPZCO5MW3WZAX2ERa3RJ7PA5QKawTRGH9Yg0tdv4ENVJeZAqFchh9mNJuHu75gKv6QkHj63ezAZBGUm1OnpHWurJM4Aa0J71hFsCr27ZCSz43IuYs7QoBomtHVJCiex6ZBRZAovNybDf5XhfyaPNt5CHhvAhnoSZAXFO8q8c2na1ndztlp1zY2ftvsc9QVZCboEwdLAQnZA4zejYvM7kZD',
success: function(json) {
    //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.posts.data.length; i++) {
        var section = json.posts.data[i].message;
        $("#tableid").append("<tr><td style='width:70px'><img id='theImg' src='img/fb.png'/></td><td><b>" + section +
            "</b></td></tr>");
       }
},
error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The Javascript SDK will handle all token-related logic for you. Why do you want to have a long-lived token in the browser?

You should use the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) and the features it provides. The only use-case to generate long-lived tokens yourself is if you want to make API calls from your server.

Since [extending and token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending) involves sending over your App Secret, you should not do that in the browser; your app secret should only be on your server.